# How can I cast a void function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, void

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
  return 20;
}

int main() {
    void (*blah)() = f;

    printf("%d\n",*((int *)blah())());  // Error is here! I need help!
    return 0;
}
```

I want to cast 'blah' back to (int *) so that I can use it as a function to return 20 in the `printf` statement, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a function pointer that does not match the function signature?

Comment: What a hack. Functions without prototypes and then reinterpreting a function pointer returning `void` to one returning `int`. I think there is no excuse possible for doing things like this.

Comment: yes, i can make 'blah' to point to whatever i want, hence saving variables :)

Comment: @Jens: Actually there is a very good excuse; it's the only way to implement the equivalent of `void *` for function pointer types. Presumably another variable would be used to hold information that would determine the actual type of the function pointed to, in order to allow it to be called correctly.

Comment: Or, if the `void (*)()` function pointer were just part of a "context" you pass in to an API that gets passed back to your callback function, you might statically know the type to cast to before calling it.

Comment: tsubasa: why not just use a `union` of function pointers?

Comment: @R. I don't think that this is a valid excuse. The other variable that you suppose to hold the (return) type could well be just a function pointer that is already correctly typed or 0 if it isn't. And if you know statically what your function is, just use that function.

Comment: You might statically know the type, but not the particular function, and in fact there may not be a finite set of possibilities if the function can be provided by a module or caller. While it's ugly, there are definitely use cases for this construct, and they correspond exactly to the use cases where you want `void *` for data pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might fix it:

```
printf("%d\n", ((int (*)())blah)() );
```

Comment: Besides the compiler (here gcc giving a warning: `initialization from incompatible pointer type` the solution works.

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be invoking the function pointed to by `blah`, and then attempting to cast its `void` return value to `int *`, which of course can't be done.

You need to cast the function pointer before invoking the function.  It is probably clearer to do this in a separate statement, but you can do it within the printf call as you've requested:

```
printf("%d\n", ((int (*)())blah)() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of initializing a void pointer and recasting later on, initialize it as an int pointer right away (since you already know it's an int function):

```
int (*blah)() = &f; // I believe the ampersand is optional here
```

To use it in your code, you simply call it like so:

```
printf("%d\n", (*blah)());
```

Comment: Why do you not want it like this?

Comment: @crashmstr my guess is that there's an external API involved, for which he doesn't have the ability to change signatures.

Comment: If "f" is an external API function, then it either returns int or not. Also, from the example, there seems to be no reason to use function pointers at all as well. So "works but not what I want" is still a little vague.

Comment: @crash, I'm sure the example is just a generic stub, but even if the OP wanted to have a void function pointer to recast later on to the appropriate type, the code would have to know ahead of time what type that function is, something that would be hard-coded anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` the int version:

```
typedef int (*foo)();

void (*blah)() = f;
foo qqq = (foo)(f);

printf("%d\n", qqq());
```